# delete duplicates from all files in the directory and keep the first occurrence

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have 50+ csv files in the directory and I want to delete the duplicates lines that may occur in any file, but keep the first occurrence of the line. Note that duplicates are not necessarily in the same file, e.g. say line in file #1 is repeated in file #45. I need to keep the line in file #1 and delete that in file #45 (modifying the original file). How can I do that in linux?

This is the code I have that deletes the duplicates in one file (modifying the original file) but it doesn't delete the duplicates if exists across different files.

```
find . -type f -exec awk '!seen[$0]++{print > "./"FILENAME".tmp"}' {} \; -exec sh -c 'mv -f "$1".tmp "$1"' sh {} \;
```

Comment: How big are the files (KB, MB, GB, TB)?

Comment: are the 50 files all in the same directory, or in subdirectories?

Comment: how many numbers does this output? `find -type f -exec bash -c 'echo "$#"' -- {} +`

Comment: `find` output is not consistently ordered. If you have files `f1`,`f2`,`f3` they can be returned as `f1`,`f3`,`f2` or `f3`,`f2`,`f1`, etc. When you say "keep the line in file #1" rather than #45, how do you decide which file is "#1" ?

Comment: I managed to solve it. The issue was that searching for duplicates in all files was very slow and clear check of my data showed that the duplicates happened in consecutive files. so this is the command that worked: 

for ((i=1; i<${#file_list[@]}-1; i++))
do
   current_file=${file_list[$i]}
   next_file=${file_list[$(($i+1))]}
   # compare next_file with current_file and
   grep -w -Ff "${next_file}" -v "${current_file}" > "${temp}"
   mv "${temp}" "${current_file}"
done

Comment: the files are not big themselves, but I have lots of them (total size is 1.5G)

Answer (score 1):

For fun, here is another way, using what at least I think is a nice one-liner, piping the outputs from command to command as the task is pieced together.

### Command

```
head -n-0 ./f* | cat -n | sort -k2 -k1n | uniq -f1 | sort -k1n | cut -f2 | awk 'match($0, /==> \.\/(.+) <==/, a) {file = a[1]; next} {print > file}'
```

### Explanation

```
head -n-0 ./f*
```

Concatenates the full content of all source files. Using `head` handily adds each file's name in the format `==> ./f1.csv <==`.

Note: using `f*` assumes files are named f1, f2 ,f3, etc, and that their precedence is in the same order. If they are named randomly, `f*` will have to be substituted for a list in order of precedence. E.G. `head -n-0 ./thisfile ./thatfile ./thirdfile`.

```
cat -n
```

Prepend a line number to each line received from head, which will be used to sort later.

```
sort -k2 -k1n
```

Produce a sorted input for `uniq`: sorted first by field 2 (the row data), and then by the prepended line number (to ensure identical rows are ordered by file precedence).

```
uniq -f1
```

Remove duplicates, and skip field one (the line number) when assessing.

```
sort -k1n
```

Re-sort the output from `uniq` by the line numbering, so rows (only the unique ones now) are back into file order.

```
cut -f2
```

Cut the line numbering from the previous output.

```
awk 'match($0, /==> \.\/(.+) <==/, a) {file = a[1]; next} {print > file}'
```

Write the newly filtered output back to each file.

`match` matches the rows with the filename pattern and using a group stores just the filename to `a`.

`{file = a[1]; next}` subsequently stores the filename from `a` into `file`, then moves to the next line so the `==> ./f1.csv <==` row is not printed.

`{print > file}` then prints each line to `file`.

Next time `match` makes a hit `a` and then `file` will be updated to the next filename so any following rows are output to the next file. And so on...

Comment: Very nice details, yet concise explanation.